# Upgrading SLX brakes, do I also need SLX rotors?

Tags: brakes, shimano, upgrades

Gearing up for my first big upgrade and recently bought a pair of Shimano SLX brakes for both my ([2009 Gary Fisher Piranha](http://www.trekbikes.com/ca/en/bikes/2009/archive/fisher/piranha/#/ca/en/archive-model/details?url=ca/en/bikes/2009/archive/fisher/piranha)) and my wife's ([2011 Trek 6000 WSD](http://www.trekbikes.com/ca/en/bikes/2011/archive/trek/6000wsd/#/ca/en/archive-model/details?url=ca/en/bikes/2011/archive/trek/6000wsd)) bikes. I'm just wondering if it's worth upgrading the rotors to SLX rotors also or can I continue to use the existing rotors? Is it safe to assume that if I have rotors that work with resin pads they'll continue to work with the new SLX resin pads? Thanks.

Comment: Upgrade from what?

Comment: @Blam: The linked bikes have Juicy 3's and Shimano M486 as stock components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Proviso - I assume your existing rotors are in good condition - if not the upgrade is a replacement of a worn component which needs doing anyway.)

It will be fine to use existing rotors.  Rotors come in all shapes and sizes and prices, so it can get confusing, but within the same size, the difference is more about balancing cost, weight and durability, the ability to shed mud and the ability to handle heat. Throw into this mix marketing and sales, and most of the information you will find is driven towards getting you to spend money you do not need to spend.

There would be advantages in upgrading, my guess is they would be very small and probably imperceptible once riding. You gave no indication how much cash you have burning a hole in your pocket, so we cannot really give you a "Is it worth it? Yes/No" answer.

Comment: Yeah I find marketing terms like "Compatible with Ice-Tech rotors" really confusing, which is why I asked. The rotors are in good condition so I'll keep them and proceed with the upgrade. Thanks for the information.